# UIAlertController disappearing instantaneously

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I present a `UIAlertController`, appearing for about half a second and disappearing, before I need to touch the OK button.
Any idea about what could cause this?

For reference, the code is below, I have been using it many times, in the past. Apart that this time I pass a caller parameter.

```
func showMessageBox(msg:String, title:String, caller:UIViewController) {
    let attribMsg = NSAttributedString(string: msg,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(23.0)])
    let userPopUp = UIAlertController(title:title,
        message:nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    userPopUp.setValue(attribMsg, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    userPopUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler:{action in}))
    caller.presentViewController(userPopUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: share the code please

Comment: show the code of how u r presting it

Comment: I edited the question to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code here and it worked fine - the alert controller waits for me to click the button before going away. Is it possible that whatever is presenting it is also dismissing it by accident? Or perhaps that the view controller inside `caller` is itself being dismissed?

Comment: The view controller inside caller is not dismissed, because when the pop up disappears it is still there.

Comment: And you're not calling it at some strange time, e.g. in `viewDidLoad()`? If you try to present a view controller at the wrong time you should see warnings in the Xcode logs.

Comment: I am not presenting the pop up from the controller itself, but from a delegate method called by it.

Comment: I can see a message: "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad", but I think it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: No, that's just one of Apple's many general error messages that happen regardless. You say it's a delegate method, which adds more scope for error: is the delegate being released, or whatever was calling the delegate?

Comment: I think your first note was right. Though "I saw the caller there", I realized it was in fact not the caller but a differrent instance of the same class as the caller. So I was fooled.